# Why call sizeof operator with two arguments?

Tags: c, sizeof

I recently came across some code that looked like:

```
if(sizeof(var,2) == 4) { ... }
```

(where `var` is a type)

I was quite surprised to see what appeared to be two arguments to the `sizeof` operator. A quick scan of the ISO/ANSI C99 standard did not yield any secrets. I couldn't come up with any reading of the grammar that allowed a comma there.

Searching Google Code, I was able to find [an example](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#YaNWgKqS-Ho/p-vxworks/i386-wrs-vxworks/sys-include/arch/ppc/toolPpc.h&q=%22sizeof(mode,2)%22&l=519) of this syntax in some PPC code.

Is this some PPC-specific syntax? What does it mean?

**EDIT:** It turns out that both what I was looking at--as well as the linked code--is syntax specific to the [WindRiver Diab compiler](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:zuQVRjmLT6sJ:https://support.windriver.com/olsPortal/download%3Bjsessionid%3D5b6397d842c51ec425e8532f3591ed7788e78b4ec5b65f0df3314c020d895127.e3yQb3uNa3aRe34MbxuMc3iNbNz0%3FdocId%3D2755+sizeof+operator+diab+ppc&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> **sizeof**(type, int-const):
>
> If int-const is 0 **sizeof** returns the size in bytes of type.
>
> If int-const is 1 **sizeof** returns the alignment of type.
>
> If int-const is 2 **sizeof** returns an integer constant designating
>   the type of type. Look up "sizeof operator" in the
>   *Diab C/C++ User's Guide* for values.

Wow, they've really overloaded the meaning of the `sizeof` operator.

**EDIT2:** Full documentation is here: http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/diab5.0ppc/c-additi.htm#3001432

Comment: It is important to this discussion to mention that "var" is a type. Because that would rule out the comma operator. But "var" in your question looks like a variable.

Comment: Renamed variable for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: On Edit: Wow, that's ... a totally unnecessary complication of the C language. C is complicated enough... If you want to be able to say the alignment, write an alignof function, or operator, if you insist. sheesh. (Not your fault David, just venting about bad language implementers...)

Comment: @Brian: I totally agree. And the fact that they used the same old name (sizeof) for new behavior makes finding information about it (or knowing where to look) very tricky indeed!

Comment: @Brian: C itself isn't that complicated... I find it remarkably simple, just certain tasks are complicated to do in C. But I do agree that overloading sizeof would be a terrible idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On further research, I discovered that this is behavior specific to the [WindRiver Diab compiler](https://support.windriver.com/olsPortal/faces/manuals_public_search_results.jspx;jsessionid=3c3b3b290f1a62d77628bfccde40eb6e31acfc6eabaa43de12efba42de5ad361.e3yQb3uMbNuLe34SahaOa3mKa3b0?action=search&prodId=382). Please see the **EDIT** in the question for details.

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like a simple application of the [comma operator](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html), which evaluates its first argument, throws away the result, then evaluates its second argument.

In this case, it's determining whether the literal `2` has size 4. The "`var`" part is irrelevant.

Comment: I thought the same thing at first, but what's the point? And if that were true, then the linked code would never work, right? The second argument is an int literal, so its size would always be the size of an integer on that architecture.

Comment: Were the comma operator being used, wouldn't it be necessary to enclose the pair in another set of parentheses?

Comment: @veefu, no, because it's sizeof(exp) and the expression just happens to be var,2...

Comment: @veefu: no, sizeof is an operator, not a function. You don't need parenthesis to "call" sizeof, "sizeof 1" works as well as "sizeof (1)". In general it's "sizeof <expression>" and in this case the expression is "(var, 2)".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a red herring.  My guess is that you are accidentally using the comma operator and sizeof is being applied to the last value.

Comment: @Rob, because I am not a master of the english language :).  Switched it to a red herring

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the comma operator is being applied and sizeof is returning the size of an integer literal.  Offhand this looks like an error on the author's part, but there could be some sinister coding happening.

sizeof expressions are not evaluated so they can be used for a number of tricky things.  One example is to provide a reference for an otherwise unreferenced variable without causing the compiler to generate any code.   See [this article](http://cnicholson.net/2009/02/stupid-c-tricks-adventures-in-assert/) on creating a better assert macro for an example.  Alexandrescu has some other examples of sizeof trickery in Modern C++ Design, if memory serves.  It's possible, but not likely, that one of these non-obvious usages is intended.

Whatever the usage, if it's not commented in this situation then it's clearly not worth the trade-off in readability and should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

*Important disclaimer: Below code is pseudo code. The **arguments to sizeof are never actually be evaluated**, with the meaning of "executed", it is always a compile time construct (and therefore one of the tools preferred by template authors, like enums).*

*note that I borrowed `auto` below from C++ (0x); it tells the compiler to deduce the type from the initializer expression and makes the examples a bit simpler*

What many don't know is that you can invoke `sizeof` validly like this:

```
auto s = sizeof int;
```

I.e., no parentheses needed. Therefore, if you pass (x,y) to `sizeof`, it is equivalent to

```
auto c = (x,y);
auto s = sizeof c;
```

or just

```
auto c = x,y;
auto s = sizeof c;
```

`x,y` is a sequence, where each part is evaluated left to right, and the sequence gets the value of the last part, in this case this is `y`. So, the original code is roughly equivalent to

```
auto s = sizeof y;
```

So it looks to me that the compiler in question does something really, really braindead, in that it introduces an extension that also compiles on other compilers, but with a totally different meaning. This is bad.

Comment: Fortunately, gcc and MSVC do not allow this. Code like `sizeof(int,2)` yields an error in both compilers similar to: "`error: expected ')' before ',' token`".

Comment: I realise my anser is imcomplete. "int" in itself is not an evaluable expression; if you write `sizeof(5,5)` it will compile.