# What meaning arguments before the function have?

Tags: c++, c, openvswitch

While I am seeing the OVS source code, I found very strange codes i never seen before.

https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/lib/ovs-rcu.h

```
void ovsrcu_postpone__(void (*function)(void *aux), void *aux);
#define ovsrcu_postpone(FUNCTION, ARG)                          \
    ((void) sizeof((FUNCTION)(ARG), 1),                         \
     (void) sizeof(*(ARG)),                                     \
     ovsrcu_postpone__((void (*)(void *))(FUNCTION), ARG))
```

I got the meaning of multi argument sizeof by searching

[Why call sizeof operator with two arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966034/why-call-sizeof-operator-with-two-arguments)
http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/diab5.0ppc/c-additi.htm#3001432

If return of FUNCTION is int and type of ARG is char, macro becomes this form.

```
((void) 4, (void) 1, ovsrcu_postpone__((void (*)(void *))(function), arg))
```

I cannot catch the roles of two arguments before ovsrcu_postpone__ method.

Comment: It looks like a way to check the compatibility of the types of `FUNCTION` and `ARG` before casting away their types (by using them in an unevaluated expression `sizeof`, which does nothing at runtime, but which must pass the typechecker). A kind of 'generic programming'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's look at the example that they give in the source code:

```
ovsrcu_postpone(free, ovsrcu_get_protected(struct flow *, &flowp));
```

This will be expanded into:

```
(
 (void) sizeof((free)(ovsrcu_get_protected(struct flow *, &flowp)), 1),
 (void) sizeof(*(ovsrcu_get_protected(struct flow *, &flowp))),
 ovsrcu_postpone__((void (*)(void *))(free), ovsrcu_get_protected(struct flow *, &flowp))
)
```

So what we have here, is some type safety, and then the expected call. Here's what I can tease out of the requirements:

- The first argument is a function with one argument.
- The second argument has at least one level of indirection (it's a pointer).

We can also understand this:

```
 sizeof(free, 1);
```

That's using the comma operator, so other than making sure the syntax is valid, it will have the same return value as `sizeof(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

From macro definition:

```
void ovsrcu_postpone__(void (*function)(void *aux), void *aux);
#define ovsrcu_postpone(FUNCTION, ARG)                          \
    ((void) sizeof((FUNCTION)(ARG), 1),                         \
     (void) sizeof(*(ARG)),                                     \
     ovsrcu_postpone__((void (*)(void *))(FUNCTION), ARG))
```

we can deduce that `ovsrcu_postpone(FUNCTION, ARG)` will be expanded to three coma-separated expressions anclosed in brackets:

```
    ((void) sizeof((FUNCTION)(ARG), 1),                         \ 1
     (void) sizeof(*(ARG)),                                     \ 2
     ovsrcu_postpone__((void (*)(void *))(FUNCTION), ARG))      \ 3
```

Coma operator evaluates expressions starting from left to right. So this code will evaluate `(void) sizeof((FUNCTION)(ARG), 1)` and `(void) sizeof(*(ARG))` and call `ovsrcu_postpone__((void (*)(void *))(FUNCTION), ARG)`. This is type of safety checking.